# Submitting Test Scores to Database

Tags: php, mysql

I finally figured out how to make a simple registration form that injects data into a database table. My code looks something like this:

```
<form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="" novalidate>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label id="llastname" for="lastname">Last Name</label></td>
      <td class="field"><input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" value="" maxlength="100"></td>
      <td class="status"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label id="lsignupsubmit" for="signupsubmit">Signup</label></td>
      <td class="field" colspan="2"><input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <?php
 include('config.php');
 $pdo = connect();
try {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO g1_members (firstname VALUES (:firstname)";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'PDOException : '.  $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</form>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to put test scores into a different database table.

When a visitor takes a test at mysite/test/gw-intro-1, after selecting their answers and clicking the Submit button, they're forwarded to mysite/test/results.php, where the code below calculates and displays test scores:

```
<?php
 $answer1 = $_POST['q1'];
 $answer2 = $_POST['q2'];
 $answer3 = $_POST['q3'];
 $answer4 = $_POST['q4'];
 $answer5 = $_POST['q5'];
 $answer6 = $_POST['q6'];
 $answer7 = $_POST['q7'];
 $answer8 = $_POST['q8'];
 $answer9 = $_POST['q9'];
 $answer10 = $Ch;

 $totalCorrect = 0;

if ($answer1 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer2 == "Jupiter") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer4 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer5 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer6 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer7 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer8 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer9 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer10) { $totalCorrect++; }

echo ''.$totalCorrect.' out of 10';
?>
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to get the value $totalCorrect into a database table - presumably without a form; it should be automatically submitted when the user clicks the Submit button.

Comment: All you need to do is to execute the insert command. `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME..`

Comment: One thing you should maybe think about doing is automating your form post set-up with a `foreach` and a custom function. You are doing a lot of manual duplication.

Comment: I see, if I just insert an execute command without a form, it will work automatically. I tried something like that, but I'll play with it some more. There are still a lot of kinks to work out. ;)

Comment: @ Rasclatt - Thx; I asked a question about that on another thread and got a foreach function; I just haven't plugged it into this demo yet.